# React Native Edit Path in SVG

Tags: android, reactjs, svg

I need to import the svg onto the screen and when I click on its elements, change the color of the path that the user clicked on. The problem is that I do not understand how to do this because my SVG have more than 20,000 lines of code

Comment: Try implementing this with a simpler file. Once you've figured it out for one element you should find it easy to adapt to something more complicated.

Comment: @RobertLongson thank you, I will try, but have some problems with importing and use svg in React Native.